# Different behavior trying to build collapsible Panels using Bootstrap/CSS

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, highcharts, bootstrap-5

Im trying to build a collapsible sliding left panel using bootstrap 5. Im almost there but having some issues.
If you have a look at the code here:  https://jsfiddle.net/dizzy0ny/86wjas9L/108/

You will see i try to achieve this two different ways. one using javascript and one using Boostrap/CSS.   The behavior are different.

1. i would like the panel to slide left.  this works for the javascript code (Toggle1 button).  But does not for toggle2 button.  in the latter's case it slides up instead
2. regardless of method used the content shown does not resize to fit the entire page width then the panel is collapsed.  And in other case when the window is smaller, if i expand the collapsed panel, a horizontal scrollbar appears as the chart does not resize to fit.  Ive tried a few styling options to try and correct this - but have thus far failed.
3. lastly - anyway to have the content area's height adjusted to fit also so the vertical scroll bar does not show?

here is the html:

```
<head>

  <!-- JQuery links  -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@6.1.2/css/fontawesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-X8QTME3FCg1DLb58++lPvsjbQoCT9bp3MsUU3grbIny/3ZwUJkRNO8NPW6zqzuW9" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.14.0-beta2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.14.0-beta2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/data.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/export-data.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/accessibility.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
      <div class="navbar-nav">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-success" id="menu-toggle1">Toggle1</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-success" id="menu-toggle3" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#sidebar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="sidebar">Toggle2</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="home" href="#">Home</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="menu1" href="#">Menu 1</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="menu2" href="#">Menu 2</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row flex-nowrap">
      <div id="sidebar" class="col-auto px-1 collapse collapse-horizontal show border-end">
       <!--left collapsible nav bar-->
        <div id="sidebar-nav" class="min-vh-100">
          <form>
            <div>
              <div class="mb-3">
                <select id="cot_contract" name="cot_contract" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
                  <option>Some Item Number 1</option>;
                  <option>Some Item Number 2</option>';
                  <option>Some Item Number 3</option>';
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="mb-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input1" name="input1" placeholder="Enter some text" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <!--main content area-->
      <main class="col ps-md-2 pt-2">
        <div id="container"></div>
      </main>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#sidebar {
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
    background: #7386D5;
    color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    padding: 5px;
    align-items: stretch;
}

#sidebar.active {
    margin-left: -250px;
}

#container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
```

and finally the javacript:

```
#sidebar {
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
    background: #7386D5;
    color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    padding: 5px;
    align-items: stretch;
}

#sidebar.active {
    margin-left: -250px;
}

#container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
```

Thanks much

**Update:**
Finally got all of this to work. the final issue of re-sizing the content and dealing with the vertical scroll bar always showing:

- added d-flex h-100 flex-column to top level container for the row
  containing the nav panel and content.
- added body/html height 100%
- main content column needs a display of 'content'.
- to fix the vertical scroll bar always showing - moved nav into top
  level div as another row. added 'h-100' 2nd row (containing the
  collapsing pane and content).

Updated and working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dizzy0ny/86wjas9L/513/

Man i hate css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_collapse_sidebar.asp) from W3School, it's possible to do the sidebar the same without jQuery in a more pure way.

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
}

Highcharts.chart('container', {

  series: [{
    data: [2, 5, 2, 3, 6, 5]
  }]

});
```

```css
.sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidebar a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidebar a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidebar .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.openbtn {
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #111;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: none;
}

.openbtn:hover {
  background-color: #444;
}

#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 16px;
}

/* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidebar {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidebar a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">×</a>
</div>

<div id="main">
  <button class="openbtn" onclick="openNav()">☰ Open Sidebar</button>
  <div id="container"></div>
</div>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/kned9yuv/

----- EDIT

To adjust the chart to your container you can use [chart.reflow()](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart.html#reflow), every time when you resize the window.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/kned9yuv/3/

Comment: yes i saw that article. unfortunately things get more complicated for real use cases involving some additional components. thats why i presented all the code above and a jsfiddle to reproduce - in hopes someone spot the reason why in my case the behavior is different.

Comment: @mike01010 let check out the improved solution, could you explain point 3 from your case?

Comment: thanks.  i can get simple examples to work. i've included a fiddle also..are u seeing anything why the behavior is different in mine between the two buttons?  from the links u provided..should be able to do it with just css, but only works w/ javascript for my example.

Comment: This different behaviour is bootstrap related, it has been programmed to close from top to bottom by default, check in the documentation.

Comment: I've marked your answer correct as it did answer the question about the difference between the two behaviors - i guess CSS bootstrap only does slide up behavior.
I still can not get reflow to work in all cases in my example:  https://jsfiddle.net/dizzy0ny/86wjas9L/145/
It works when collapsing, but not expanding.  if you see anything obvious. please let me know.